# Topics Subscriptions not active on new token

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are planning on migrating to using topics through FCM for our application.
I have done some tests and have noticed a weird behaviour (looks very much like a bug).
When receiving a new token for the same InstanceID the https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/ endpoint still shows previously active topic subscriptions for this instance id.
But notifications sent to this topic do not arrive on the device.

These are the steps I took:

- Get a token in the Android SDK

`FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(projectId, scope)` => **ABC:123**

- Subscribe to a topic in the Android SDK

`FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(topicName)`

- Verify the topic was subscribed to using the API call: https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/ABC:123?details=true

```
    {
      "applicationVersion": "1",
      "connectDate": "2019-02-18",
      "attestStatus": "UNKNOWN",
      "application": "com.foo.bar",
      "scope": "*",
      "authorizedEntity": "12345",
      "rel": {
        "topics": {
          "topicName": {
            "addDate": "2019-02-18"
          }
        }
      },
      "connectionType": "WIFI",
      "appSigner": "XXXXXXX",
      "platform": "ANDROID"
    }
```

- Send a notification to the topic => notification arrives
- Delete the token in the Android SDK

`FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteToken(projectId, scope)`

- Get a new token in the Android SDK

`FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(projectId, scope)` => **ABC:456**

- Verify the topic was subscribed to using the API call: https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/ABC:456?details=true

```
    {
      "applicationVersion": "1",
      "connectDate": "2019-02-18",
      "attestStatus": "UNKNOWN",
      "application": "com.foo.bar",
      "scope": "*",
      "authorizedEntity": "12345",
      "rel": {
        "topics": {
          "topicName": {
            "addDate": "2019-02-18"
          }
        }
      },
      "connectionType": "WIFI",
      "appSigner": "XXXXXXX",
      "platform": "ANDROID"
    }
```

- Just to verify this is the new response for the deleted token.
  https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/ABC:123?details=true

```
{ "error": "No information found about this instance id." }
```

- Send a notification to the topic => **notification does not arrive!**

This behavior does not restore. (We waited a full day).
Why does the info endpoint show that the new token was subscribed to the topic, but in reality is not registered at all?
The only fix seems to be re-subscribing the new token on the topic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you think it's not behaving as expected, you should contact Firebase support directly and file a bug report with your steps to reproduce the problem.  http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features